# Why does both the if AND the else condition seem to execute in this code (Python)?

Tags: python, if-statement

I know that similar questions have been posted on this site before, but I truly think this case is different so hear me out.

I have some simple Python code that creates a 2D list of characters (i.e. strings of length 1), tries to process the 2D list, and print it out. Here it is:

```
def printGrid(image):
    for row in range(len(image)):
        for col in range(len(image[row])):
            print(image[row][col], end='')
        print()
    print()


def invert(image):
    for row in range(len(image)):
        for col in range(len(image[row])):
            if image[row][col] == '.':
                image[row][col] = 'X'
            else:
                image[row][col] = '.'


grid = [['.'] * 10] * 10    # 2D square of '.'
printGrid(grid)
invert(grid)
printGrid(grid)
```

I was expecting the code to print out 1 square of `.`s and another of `X`s, like this:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........

XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXX
```

but instead I got 2 squares of `.`s, like this:

```
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........

..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
```

After trying to debug for a while, I found that if I commented out the `else` block in the `invert` function, then I get the expected output (you can try running the code for yourself to see). This led me to conclude that both the `if` block AND the `else` block are executed. Does anyone know why this may be happening? (I'm using Python 3.6.1 btw)

P.S. I discovered that this bug apparently only appears for certain grid sizes. For example, if the size of `grid` is 5, 7 or 9, then the output is as expected. But if it's something like 6, 8 or 10, then the output is not as expected (apparently the bug only occurs for even-numbers of size?).

Comment: `['.'] * 10` creates a single list. When you then do ` * 10` to it, you now have 10 references to the same exact list. I don't mean a list with the same items in it; it's the same place in memory. When you then assign something in that list, it affects the entire outer list. What you need is to make a bunch of lists: `[['.'] * 10 for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: @zondo oh ok well your fix definitely does work and gives the output I was expecting, so thanks for that. Though I'm still confused as to why it was working with odd-sized squares (e.g. 9 by 9, 7 by 7) and not even-sized ones.